# Access variable outside function in native geocoder

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using ionic native geocoder for getting coordinates from string provides. Country is string provided for countries.
coordinates gives required latitude and longitude from below code.
variable coordinatesData gives actual result containing latitude and longitude inside the function.
If I try to print **coordinatesData** outside function it gives undefined.

```
this.nativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode(Country).then((coordinates: NativeGeocoderForwardResult[])=> {
let coordinatesData=JSON.stringify(coordinates, null, 2) 
this.map.animateCamera( {
            target: {
                lat: coordinates[0].latitude, 
                lng: coordinates[0].longitude
            }
            , zoom: 4, duration: 500
        }
        );
        let marker: Marker=this.map.addMarkerSync( {
            position: {
                lat: parseFloat(coordinates[0].latitude), 
                lng: parseFloat(coordinates[0].longitude)
            }
            , animation: GoogleMapsAnimation.DROP
        }
        );
    }

    ) .catch((error: any)=> (error));
    console.log(coordinatesData) // undefined
```

I want the same result from variable coordinatesData outside the function as I am getting inside function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. `let` values will not be available outside the function, so use `var`

```
var coordinatesData= ""; //define the variable outside your call.
this.nativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode(Country).then((coordinates: NativeGeocoderForwardResult[])=> {
coordinatesData=JSON.stringify(coordinates, null, 2);
 this.map.animateCamera( {
        target: {
            lat: coordinates[0].latitude, 
            lng: coordinates[0].longitude
        }
        , zoom: 4, duration: 500
    }
    );
    let marker: Marker=this.map.addMarkerSync( {
        position: {
            lat: parseFloat(coordinates[0].latitude), 
            lng: parseFloat(coordinates[0].longitude)
        }
        , animation: GoogleMapsAnimation.DROP
    }
    );
}

) .catch((error: any)=> (error));
console.log(coordinatesData) // undefined
```

**updated answer:**

```
var coordinatesData =  this.nativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode(Country).then((coordinates: NativeGeocoderForwardResult[])=> {
 this.map.animateCamera( {
        target: {
            lat: coordinates[0].latitude, 
            lng: coordinates[0].longitude
        }
        , zoom: 4, duration: 500
    }
    );
    let marker: Marker=this.map.addMarkerSync( {
        position: {
            lat: parseFloat(coordinates[0].latitude), 
            lng: parseFloat(coordinates[0].longitude)
        }
        , animation: GoogleMapsAnimation.DROP
    }
    );
  logData(JSON.stringify(coordinates, null, 2));
}

) .catch((error: any)=> (error));

function logData(coordinatesData){
  console.log(coordinatesData) // undefined
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution, but in console it shows nothing but blank.

Comment: Now I am getting output : [object Promise]

Comment: can you try now